# ¿Como pasar un elemento repetido (que se repita x n° de veces) de una lista a otra lista?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, sql-server-2012

Hola amigos mis mas cordiales saludos a todos... Soy nuevo programando y nuevo en el foro.

Estoy haciendo un sistemilla en asp.net con entity framework en cual tengo un calendario (

```
//De esta manera obtengo una lista (string) de fechas desde la db 
            foreach (var datoFinal in fechasList)
            {
                fecha = datoFinal.Fecha.ToString();

                fechas.Add(fecha);

            }
```

Mi problema es el siguiente, como saber que elementos que son fechas se repiten. Luego de determinar eso, pasar las fechas a otra lista pero solo aquellas que se repitan, ej > 1

desde sql se hace de esta manera

```
SELECT columna, COUNT( * ) AS alias FROM Tabla GROUP BY columna HAVING COUNT(*)>1 ;
```

pero no logro insertar esa consulta en el programa. He intentado de todo jaja 
Ahora bien cuando hago un consulta clasica como esta funciona perfect.

```
var fechasList = fechasReserva.Practica_FechaReserva.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM FechaReserva").ToList<FechaReserva>();
```

saludos y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías realizar algo así

```
List<DateTime> fechas = new List<DateTime>();
fechas.Add(DateTime.Now);
fechas.Add(DateTime.Now);
fechas.Add(DateTime.Now);
fechas.Add(Convert.ToDateTime("28-09-1989"));
fechas.Add(Convert.ToDateTime("02-04-2016"));

// extraemos los items repetidos
List<DateTime> repetidos = fechas.GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();

// Creas una nueva lista que contendrá tus datos repetidos
List<DateTime> fechas2 = new List<DateTime>();

foreach(DateTime r in repetidos)
{
   // Agregas cada item al nuevo listado
   fechas2.Add(r);
}
```

Nos comentas si es lo que deseas :)

Comment: era exactamente lo que necesitaba muchas gracias.. alfiiin estaba pegado con eso.. gracias totales

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el [`GroupBy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2) de LinQ:

```
var fechas_agrupadas = fechasList.GroupBy(fecha => fecha);
```

La instrucción anterior te crea una lista de listas en que cada sub-lista tiene todos los elementos iguales; si quieres sólo aquellas que tienen más de una repetición, usa [`Where`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
var fechas_muy_repetidas = fechasList.GroupBy(fecha => fecha).Where(grupo => grupo.Count() > 1);
```

Si lo quieres en una sola lista, tendrás que desagrupar, para ello usa [`SelectMany`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
var fechas_muy_repetidas = fechasList.GroupBy(fecha => fecha)
                                     .Where(grupo => grupo.Count() > 1)
                                     .SelectMany(grupo => grupo);
```

Pero si no quieres repeticiones, usa [`Distinct`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
var fechas_muy_repetidas = fechasList.GroupBy(fecha => fecha)
                                     .Where(grupo => grupo.Count() > 1)
                                     .SelectMany(grupo => grupo)
                                     .Distinct();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo... lo del distinct tanbn lo necesitaba gracias totales =D